# Check if lock screen instantly with power button enabled/disabled

Tags: android, lockscreen

By going to **Settings** -> **Security** -> **Screen Lock** -> **Power button instantly locks**, we can enable or disable this feature. However, is there a way to check, by code, if this is enabled or disabled by user?

I wasn't able to find the answer so any help is more than welcome.